# Why getting Cross index error using np.ix_

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, indexing

Why does this error occur while working with `np.ix_`?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,3).reshape(1,2)
print(a)

k_r = [[1,1],[1,-1]]

r = np.zeros((10,10),int)
r[np.ix_([a],[a])]= k_r

print(r)
```

Error:

> ValueError: Cross index must be 1 dimensional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that the cross index must be one-dimensional, but `a = np.arange(1,3).reshape(1,2)` creates a 2D array. Furthermore, you're adding yet another dimension (sort of, but not really) by wrapping the arrays in lists, `r[np.ix_([a],[a])]`.

Fix these things and you get:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,3)
print(a)

k_r = [[1,1],[1,-1]]

r = np.zeros((10,10),int)
r[np.ix_(a,a)]= k_r
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I understand the problem.
First you should remove the "[]" around your a's like this

```
r[np.ix_(a,a)]= k_r
```

It seems like np.ix_(a, a) wants a on the format: a = [x, x] where x is.
Your current a is on the format: [[1 2]]
An alternative way of creating your a can be:

```
a = [i for i in range(1,3)]
```

If this does not solve your problem you can check out this page: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html